# Как берутся проекты для разработки

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

К примеру клиент обратился ко мне и просит чтобы я добавил для его сайта некоей функциональности или что-то другое не важно, как именно происходит передача сайта? к примеру он даёт мне ссылку сайта на гитхабе или как-то мне передаёт файлы? Как происходит этот процесс или какие к примеру есть варианты?

Comment: Вариантов может быть множество. Вам могут дать ссылку на гит с проектом, могут проект просло по почте прислать, могут дать не весь проект, а только нужные файлы, могут ссылку на ftp дать, если сайт на cms какой-нибудь, могут дать креды для авторизации на сайте этой cms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Клиент даёт FTP доступы к хостингу - логин, пароль, домен. При помощи них разработчик может удаленно управлять данными ( https://filezilla.ru/article/chto-takoe-ftp )